# References For SharePoint In C# Winform App

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

I am working on a windows forms app and trying to connect to a sharepoint site.  I do not have sharepoint installed on my PC so from my googling I have leant that I must use client side code.

When I right click references in my project and go to add reference the only one that has Sharepoint is

> Microsoft.Sharepoint.FirefoxPlugin

I do not believe that is what I am after.  How do I  get the client side DLLs required to connect to sharepoint from my windows form app?

**EDIT**
I tried following the guide in this link, but I do not have the .dll located in this location as the link shows

> Add the following assemblies from hive 15 (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI).

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the SharePoint CSOM SDK and install, then the dll can be found in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI

[SharePoint 2013 CSOM Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install the sharepoint client nuget packages

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll/

Comment: What version of .Net framework should my project be to use this?  I have tried 4.0 and 4.6 and get error